# fiddler dll loading but not working on other machines

Tags: c#, dll, fiddler

I've recently made a Fiddler .dll that loads correctly but doesn't seem to work properly on other machines but my own.

After remote debugging on a colleague's pc it appear that 'GetRequestBodyAsString()' always returns Null for him.

Does anyone have an idea why this might be happening? I ran out of ideas.

Thank you!

Update:

```
    public void AutoTamperResponseAfter(Session oSession) {
    string body = oSession.GetRequestBodyAsString();
    // other code
    }
```

'body' will just have the whole content of the event body and will look something like this for me:

0.9.0.1|SFR.RawTemperature|2015-04-10T12:02:27.921z||e44b81e7.22166f1b.e547c7f5.28ed5c01.02|0|0|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000|UBMN.1|100|65793|h0:64:64|54.|57.|57.|54.25|50.5|51.|51.25|50.75|49.5|51.25|51.75|51.75|52.25|53.25|54.75|52.5|49.5|49.|49.75|49.5|49.|50.|49.5|49.25|50.75|48.75|49.|49.25|49.5|51.|52.25|52.25

Comment: Post some code. What is the function supposed to return?

Comment: What version of Fiddler does the *broken user*? Is the HTTP method of the request `POST` or something else? If you look at the request in Fiddler's Inspectors, do you see the expected body?

Comment: I recently updated to the same version as my buddy - 4.4.9.6 too see if that's where the problem was coming from, but that didn't change anything. Looking in Fiddler's inspectors, I'm definitely seeing the events I need and their body, but nothing's getting through on his machine at the mentioned method.

Comment: So it seems it works correctly when uninstalling any older Fiddler version and installing the latest. Weird, since I developed it on an older version, but I'll take it :)

Answer (score 1):

So in the end, it seems that when having the Stream option active, these sort of methods return Null when placed in AutoTamperResponseAfter (..and when I re-installed Fiddler I forgot to re-activate it, thus thinking it was the latest version that fixed the problem).

After reading http://fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/streaming.asp I moved them to 'AutoTamperResponseBefore' and are not returning data correctly.
Thanks for bearing with me.